# SED command doesn't write the correct variable

Tags: bash

I tried to write a variable into a file by using `SED` command.But, it's writing a not correct output.

Below is my bash script :

```
#!/bin/bash
AMOUNT_OF_USERS=$1
IN_FILE=script1.txt
HOST=localhost
USER_NAME=SDK
for (( i = 2; i <= $AMOUNT_OF_USERS; i++ ))
do
    OUT_FILE=script$i.txt

    PORT1=55001
    let NEW_PORT=$PORT1-1+$i

    USER_NUMBER=1
    NEW_USER_NUMBER=$i

    PORT_TO_REPLACE="$HOST $PORT1"
    PORT_TO_REPLACE_WITH="$HOST $NEW_PORT"
    cp $IN_FILE $OUT_FILE
    echo $PORT_TO_REPLACE_WITH
    sed -i -e "s/$USER$USER_NUMBER/$USER$NEW_USER_NUMBER/g" $OUT_FILE
    sed -i -e "s/$PORT_TO_REPLACE/$PORT_TO_REPLACE_WITH/g" $OUT_FILE
    
done
```

when echoing $PORT_TO_REPLACE_WITH, it shows correct value.
But inside the output file, it's not correct for the cycle upper than 9.

[image]

Comment: Put `set -x` at the beginning of the script to get an execution trace and see what's happening as it runs. Also, I'd recommend running the script past [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) and fixing what it points out.

Comment: @GordonDavisson, it shows the correct one, but the final output still not correct.
 sed -i -e s/1/10/g script10.txt
+ sed -i -e 's/localhost 55001/localhost 55010/g' script10.txt
+ (( i++  ))
+ (( i <= 150 ))
+ OUT_FILE=script11.txt
+ PORT1=55001
+ let NEW_PORT=55001-1+11
+ USER_NUMBER=1
+ NEW_USER_NUMBER=11
+ PORT_TO_REPLACE='localhost 55001'
+ PORT_TO_REPLACE_WITH='localhost 55011'
+ cp script1.txt script11.txt
+ echo localhost 55011
localhost 55011
+ sed -i -e s/1/11/g script11.txt
+ sed -i -e 's/localhost 55001/localhost 55011/g' script11.txt
+ (( i++  ))

Comment: `sed -i -e 's/localhost 55001/localhost 55011/g'` will turn "55001" into "550011".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as Gordon advised

```
sed -i -e 's/localhost 55001/localhost 55011/g' will turn "55001" into "550011".
```

Thanks!